# SQL Name search with apostrophe, hyphen, Double uppercase

Tags: mysql

There is a search filter with alphabet.

[image]

I would like the filter to work if I click 'D' it then displays all artist's names like:

```
David McDonald
Alice Duncan
Daniel O'Neill
Beth Douglas-Bain
```

The artist table has a column 'name' which contains first, middle and surname, including apostrophes, hyphens, and double uppercase.

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM `artist` WHERE `name` REGEXP BINARY 'D[a-z]'
```

however, that didn't work properly.

**I can only use the query from 'WHERE clause' so I cannot use the query from SELECT.**

Some problem examples are:

- Click 'O' but O'Neill not showing up
- Click 'B' then Douglas-Bain showing up, should be 'D', McDonald has same problem too.

The surname of McDonald, O'neill, Douglas-Bain, those makes the query not working well as McDonald and Douglas-Bain have two uppercases, so it appears when I hit 'D'. O'Neill has an apostrophe and double uppercase and I cannot figure it out.

I would really appreciate it if some SQL expert can help me.

Comment: The question is a little bit unclear, can you please post a sample list of names and desired output?

Comment: What is preventing you from modifying the select part?

Comment: @user5226582 Sorry cant explain well but updated, is that more clear?

Comment: What is preventing you from modifying the select part?

Comment: @Takarii, Just my circumstance, cannot use from select. Need to use query from Where.

Comment: are you able to use a select within the where?

Comment: @Takarii, yes I'm be able to use select in where clause

Comment: @hasmai, Just a thought, you could do a case-sensitive search for capital letters? Assuming your data is clean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'(^|[^A-Za-z''])lettervalue'
```

where `lettervalue` is the selected letter

Tested on the following list of names and got successes on all.

```
Daniel Grass
Daniel House
Ronald O'House
Craig McHouse
Tina Dreamer
Orion Fantastic
```

As required,

`'(^|[^A-Za-z''])O'` pulls "Ronald O'House" and "Orion Fantastic",

`'(^|[^A-Za-z''])H'` pulls out "Daniel House" (but ignores Craig McHouse)

`'(^|[^A-Za-z''])M'` pulls out "Craig McHouse"

Comment: Thank you for your query, you mean the query with REGEXP BINARY? Query still pulls "O’Sullivan" if I query "'WHERE `name` REGEXP BINARY '(^|[^A-Za-z''])S' " :( But it pulls O’Sullivan for click 'O'. It's close!

Comment: @hasmai It's not doing that in my test table. if i run `SELECT * 
FROM  artist 
WHERE name REGEXP 
BINARY  '(^|[^A-Za-z''])S'` then "Ronald O'Sulivan" is ignored. Are there any spaces before or after the `'`?

Comment: @hasmai I managed to reproduce the result you were getting when running  it on my own server, the regex performs correctly. It breaks, however, if you do `' '` (note the space between the apostrophes). Check your query and see if thats the case

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select * from artist where name like '%D%' or name like '%d%';
```

Comment: That would give exactly rhe same output. It would catch McDonald as well as Ronald (which don't start with D)

Comment: @highnelly, as Takarii said, your answer isnt for my question. Sorry but thank for your reply anyway.